# HTTP Status 404 – Not Found - error while deploying java application in nginx container

Tags: java, nginx, tomcat

I am getting 404 not found error while deploying java container in Nginx. Please help. Below is the error message:

HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message /java/

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

My Nginx entries are as below:

```
location ~* /java {
proxy_pass http://java:8080;
root /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/spring-petclinic-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war;           
index  index.html;
}
```

Comment: are you using ProxyPass in Nginx?

Comment: yes i am using proxypass in nginx

Comment: share your configuration in question.

Comment: can you have a look and suggest please.

Comment: Still, it is not clear. share java backend server details in question.